# Can I filter elements based on searchbox input in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, jss

I'm incredibly new to react and web development in general and I wanted to start by making a very simple shopping cart app. I found a nice tutorial on youtube for it, and am now trying to expand on it a bit. I wanted to add a search bar that filters out elements on the home-page as you type in it.

```
const Home = (props) => {
  function handleChange(e){
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  return (

    <div>
      <Row align="middle" className='title'> **search bar**
        <Input placeholder="Search for a school" onChange={handleChange} />
      </Row>

      <Row align="middle" className='title'>
        <Divider orientation="left"><b>Category E Schools</b></Divider>
      </Row>

      <Row align="middle" className='container'>
        **Every item for sale is in a Col element**
        <Col className = "Princeton University" xs={0} md={11} align="left">
          <div className='image'>
              <img src={Princeton} alt="Princeton University" />
              <h3>Princeton</h3>
              <h3>$1100.00</h3>
              <button onClick={() => props.addBasket('princeton')} className='addToCart cart1' href='#'>Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
        </Col>
```

I'm using AntDesign Row-Col components, and my thought was to define a className for each Col. I was hoping that with the className I could implement the handleChange function to directly remove elements whose classNames don't contain the letters typed into the input bar. Sorry for the beginner-level work going on here.

Comment: so what is the question? what's not working?
btw, you can code in codesandbox, and share a link. this way it's easier to see what's your issue

Answer (score 0):

Pat of the genius of react is that you can abstract your components and render them dynamically. to do this I would create a reusable component for all items and then render them dynamically.
Example:

1. first create an item component

```
const Item = (props) => (
        <Col className = "Princeton University" xs={0} md={11} align="left">
          <div className='image'>
              <img src={props.image} alt={props.title} />
              <h3>{props.title}</h3>
              <h3>{props.cost}</h3>
              <button onClick={() => props.addBasket('princeton')} className='addToCart cart1' href='#'>Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
        </Col>
)
}
```

2. add your items to state and render your state dynamically
3. also here I added state to search and set up two way binding between my input and my state value
4. i also added the filter method to my dynamic rendering of the items

i would recommend adding a library like loadash and using the debounce function so that the results re-render once 350ms after the user finishes typing instead of re-rendering on every single keystroke from the user

```
const Home = (props) => {
   const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {name: Princeton, price: 140000.00, img: http:princetonimages.com/f313b},
])
   const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
   const renderItems = (items) => (items.map(item => <Item {...item} />))

  return (

    <div>
      <Row align="middle" className='title'> **search bar**
        <Input 
        placeholder="Search for a school" 
        onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} 
        value={search}
        />
      </Row>

      <Row align="middle" className='title'>
        <Divider orientation="left"><b>Category E Schools</b></Divider>
      </Row>

     <Row align="middle" className='container'>
     {renderItems(state.items.filter(search))}
     </Row>
     )

}
```